# Canvas (Kinetic.JS) - cloned group doesn't appear?

Tags: html, canvas, clone, shapes, kineticjs

I'm playing with Kinetic and can't seem to figure out why a group I'm cloning won't appear.

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DgwLd/3/**

I can clone shapes no problem - it's just groups that don't appear. The documentation confirms that groups can be cloned, so I'm not sure what's up here. Here's the code from the Fiddle:

```
//group and original circle - appears fine
layer.add(new Kinetic.Group({id: 'group'}));
stage.get('#group')[0].add(new Kinetic.Circle({
    fill: 'orange',
    x: 200,
    y: 50,
    radius: 30
}));

//clone of group at different Y pos - doesn't appear
layer.add(stage.get('#group')[0].clone({y: 120}));
```

**UPDATE** - it seems cloning a group doesn't make a deep copy. This is verifiable by console logging the group - `console.log(stage.get('#group2'))` and you'll see its `children` collection is empty). Is this a bug? Not sure why you'd ever want to clone a group without its constituents.

Any thoughts? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you figured it out yourself - indeed, making a group clone, or in fact a clone of any container, performs a shallow copy.

Actually, looking at the source code may be more informative than anything else:

```
clone: function(obj) {
    // instantiate new node
    var classType = this.shapeType || this.nodeType;
    var node = new Kinetic[classType](this.attrs);

    /*
     * copy over user listeners
     */
    for(var key in this.eventListeners) {
        var allListeners = this.eventListeners[key];
        for(var n = 0; n < allListeners.length; n++) {
            var listener = allListeners[n];
            /*
             * don't include kinetic namespaced listeners because
             *  these are generated by the constructors
             */
            if(listener.name.indexOf('kinetic') < 0) {
                // if listeners array doesn't exist, then create it
                if(!node.eventListeners[key]) {
                    node.eventListeners[key] = [];
                }
                node.eventListeners[key].push(listener);
            }
        }
    }

    // apply attr overrides
    node.setAttrs(obj);
    return node;
}
```

As you can see, all it does is instantiate a new node with the current node's attributes, and then copy over the event listeners. This is probably by design - generally you want to take the path of least resistance, and this implementation is alright when you consider that the `.clone()` method exists for any general node (it's not specifically for containers).

It does seem like there should be something like a `.deepclone()` method for containers specifically, though. Maybe something like:

```
deepclone: function(obj) {
    var node = this.clone(obj);

    if (this.children) {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.children.length; i++) {
            node.add(this.children[i].clone();
        }
    }

    return node;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I get the reasoning for shallow cloning but, as you say, I certainly think there should be a means to deep clone. In my case, I have complex groups representing characters in a game, and I want to clone the whole group. I could put each character on a layer, I guess. Which further blurs the lines of definition between groups and layers, but I guess that's OK.